# Convert plain text lists into HTML lists using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array, html-lists

I frequently receive text lists in PDF format that are hierarchical (usually three levels deep). I would like to get these into HTML lists so that they can be styled with CSS and be made more presentable. Due to the volume of data, I am trying to automate the process with JavaScript.

### Example source data:

```
・First Level 1 list item
– First Level 2 list item, which is a subset of the first Level 1 list item.
– Second Level 2 list item, which is a subset of the first Level 1 list item.
♦ First Level 3 list item, which is a subset of the second Level 2 list item.
・Second Level 1 list item.
```

### Example goal:

```
<ul>
    <li>First Level 1 list item</li>
        <ul>
            <li>First Level 2 list item, which is a subset of the first Level 1 list item.</li>
            <li>Second Level 2 list item, which is a subset of the first Level 1 list item.
                <ul>
                    <li>First Level 3 list item, which is a subset of the second Level 2 list item.</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    <li>Second Level 1 list item.</li>
</ul>
```

### Progress so far:

I've determined that I can match Level 1 list items with this regex: `/^・.+$/gm`

And match Level 2 list items with this regex: `/^\–.+$/gm`

And Level 3 with this one: `/^♦.+$/gm`

Or simply delimit *all* of the list levels at once by combining those: `string.match(/(^・.+$)|(^\–.+$)|(^♦.+$)/gm);`

Now knowing how to match the different types of items, I am trying to figure out how to sort them. Conceptually, if I have them all in one array (let's use simple color coding for the next example), then it should be possible to create a function that can identify the patterns and make a *multidimensional array* in the correct hierarchy, and then another function to output that content padded with HTML tags in their proper places.

**A visualization of conversion of a one-dimensional array to a multidimensional array based on type:**

[image]

Let's say that in the simplified example above we have just a string of three letters corresponding to the colors - **r**, **g**, **b**.

So that might look like: `rrgbrgbrgbbrggbr`

I've been experimenting and trying to get this kind of structure into a multidimensional array.

I believe one dimension below Level 3 will be needed to hold the actual text strings. And one dimension above Level 1 will be needed to encompass each whole list. So a structure like this:

```
list
[
    level1
    [
        level2
        [
            level3
            [   
                string
                ["list item text"]
            ]
        ]
    ]
]
```

Here's where I'm having some trouble figuring out how to sort all of this. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Why concat them all into one array? Can't you just match each level one by one and push them accordingly?

Comment: @Darkrum Sure! If that's a better solution, great! I just wanted to explain my approach so far, and that's what was easiest for me to conceptualize. But I don't insist on doing it that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regexp not needed.

```js
var log = console.log;
var data = `・First Level 1 list item
– First Level 2 list item, which is a subset of the first Level 1 list item.
– Second Level 2 list item, which is a subset of the first Level 1 list item.
♦ First Level 3 list item, which is a subset of the second Level 2 list item.
・Second Level 1 list item.`;
//split text to array of string. One item per line
data = data.split("\n");
var firstChar,prevFirstChar = "";
//our output struct
var struct = [];
var cursor = struct;
//we need only one token for return to first level
var lvl1Key = "・";
var prevnode = {};

data.forEach(line=>{
    //get token
    firstChar = line.charAt(0);
    let node = {
        str : line.slice(1),
        child : []
    };
    if (firstChar == lvl1Key) {
      //return to root
      cursor = struct;
    } else if (firstChar != prevFirstChar) {
      //move up if token change and it is not root token
      cursor = prevnode.child;
    }
    cursor.push(node);
    prevnode = node;
    prevFirstChar = firstChar;
});
log(struct);
//Ok, we get struct, convert this to html
//offset for formating
const offsetSize = 2;
//recursive function node - array of { str : "string", childs : [nodes]}
var toHtml = function(node, offset = "") {
    var ret = offset + "<ul>\n";
    offset += " ".repeat(offsetSize);
    node.forEach(rec=>{
        ret += offset + "<li>" + rec.str + "</li>\n";
        //if array not empty add html for childs
        if (rec.child.length) {
            ret += toHtml(rec.child, offset + " ".repeat(offsetSize));
        }
    });
    offset = offset.slice(offsetSize);
    ret += offset + "</ul>\n";
    return ret;
}
log(toHtml(struct));
```

Comment: Excellent, thank you! Would you mind explaining the gist of how the code works?

Comment: Ok, wait a minute.

Comment: @Mentalist you don't need all tokens for top level lists, because any non root token, different from token before, move item down on hierarhy. You just need iterate over items and remember node in hierarhy to insert them.

Comment: Thanks. The comments you added to the code are helpful. I about half way understand how it works now. My remaining questions (if you don't mind answering) are: ・`firstChar` & `prevFirstChar` - what do these do?
・what is `struct`?
・`cursor` - is that for iterating through loops?
・what's going on with `prevnode`?
・how does `offsetSize` work, and why is it 2?
・what's going on with `ret` before it returns?

Comment: `struct` - root object with tree. `cursor` pointer for this tree. We must keep place to insert new nodes. `firstChar`, `prevFirstChar` - first char of string, our marker ('・','–','♦', ...) - current and old, we go deep in tree if they not equals. `prevnode` - last inserted node, we insert in his `child` array if markers is different.   `offsetSize` number of spaces for indent in result html. Evety call `toHtml` incraces offset. Aslo I add and remove spaces after <ul> and before </ul>. 2 - number of spaces. It can be 0 or 4 or else. `ret` - return value, just html string for append every time.

Comment: Thank you for the additional explanation. That is helpful.